# Java String matches and replaceAll differ in matching parentheses

Tags: java, regex

I have strings with parentheses and also escaped characters. I need to match against these characters and also delete them. In the following code, I use matches() and replaceAll() with the same regex, but the matches() returns false, while the replaceAll() seems to match just fine, because the replaceAll() executes and removes the characters. Can someone explain?

```
String input = "(aaaa)\\b";

boolean matchResult = input.matches("\\(|\\)|\\\\[a-z]+");
System.out.printf("matchResult=%s\n", matchResult);

String output = input.replaceAll("\\(|\\)|\\\\[a-z]+", "");
System.out.printf("INPUT: %s --> OUTPUT: %s\n", input, output);
```

Prints out:

```
matchResult=false
INPUT: (aaaa) --> OUTPUT: aaaa
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What `matches`  is doing has already [been explained by Binyamin Sharet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10578267/626273). I want to extend this a bit.

Java does not have a "findall" or a "g" modifier like other languages have it to get all matches at once.

The Java `Matcher` class knows only two methods to use a pattern against a string (without replacing it)

- [`matches()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches%28%29): matches the whole string against the pattern
- [`find()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29): returns the next match

If you want to get all things that fits your pattern, you need to use `find()` in a loop, something like this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern
    .compile("\\(|\\)|\\\\[a-z]+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
while(m.find()){
    System.out.println(m.group(0));
}
```

or if you are only interested if your pattern exists in the string

```
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
} else {
    System.out.println("not found");
}
```

Comment: I changed my original code for matches to be the following, where I added .* to the beginning and end of each pattern: inputString.matches(".*\\(.*|.*\\).*|.*\\\\[a-z]+.*"). So now that matches substrings, which is what I really want. I would rather not use Pattern and Matcher for such a simple task.

Comment: You sound like you would exactly know what you are talking about. It was a pleasure to help you.

Answer (score 5):

`matches` matches **the whole** input, not part of it.

The regular expression `\(|\)|\\[a-z]+` doesn't describe the whole word, but only parts of it, so in your case it fails.

Comment: It should be in comment not in answer.

Comment: @BhavikAmbani - I disagree, this is the explanation why matches fails when replaceAll works.

Comment: @BhavikAmbani: This is *absolutely* an answer. The question is why matches is behaving differently to replaceAll, and the answer is simply that `replaceAll` is replacing *part* of the input whereas `matches` matches the *whole* input. In what way is it *not* an answer?

Comment: It would be a better answer if it suggested a fix to the code.

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 - It would be a better answer for a different question. I saw no request for such a fix. besides, the fix is pretty straight forward.